# Getting Connectiontimedout error when creating a remote SocketServer in Java

Tags: java, sockets, server

In the socket programming i am able to connect to the server socket when it is on the same pc i.e 127.0.0.1 but when my friend at a remote location runs the server program and i try to connect to it it shows the Connectiontimedout Error.

I'm giving the ip address and port number right.

Do i need to add something extra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access server remotely, your friend should bind the server to an IP address which is accessible from your machine. This will not be the case if your friend's ISP or wifi router has allocated a [private IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) to him.

In such case both of you can join a [Virtual Private Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) to be on the same network.

Another option is [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding). If both of you can access a common machine then your friend can forward a port from the common machine to the application server's port to his machine. Now you can access your friends application server by accessing the socket at forwarded port on common machine.

If both of you are already on the same network then it might be possible that the server is listening on 127.0.0.1 interface only.

Answer (score 0):

There are possibly other middle-boxes that do NAT (Network Address Translation) in the path between you and your friend.  These normally prevent the initiation of TCP or other connections over the Internet.

Try doing the same with both of you on the same LAN (Local Area Network) or with a Hamachi VPN to simulate a LAN over the Internet.

Another possibility is configuring your  router/NAT at your location to forward the port for your application to the IP address of your machine.  In this case make sure to give your friend your public IP (you can get that with http://checkip.dyndns.org/).